Book about a girl who is sentenced to death by robot elders for idolizing a man who was considered dangerous to her society
I'm seeking a book I would have read about 20 years ago.
It's set within a totalitarian society that survived a world-changing event that was either war or a catastrophe. There are walls enclosing the city. A girl goes to school and is encouraged to write her paper on her hero. Her hero is a man that possibly worked on the wall. He was meeting with someone from outside the society and either planned to leave with her or let her in. They were both killed to keep the city safe. After writing and presenting her school paper, robot "elders" order for her death, as her idolizing this person is dangerous to the safety of the society.

Was this a whole novel or short story? The plot seems a little thin for a whole novel. Or is this just the start of the book?

I'm bullet pointing as much as possible it was a full book in the library at school.

Are there any  other details you can remember? Even small details can be helpful in jogging memories.

Faintly rings of Genesis by Bernard Beckett but the details don't quite fit.

It actually is Genesis by Bernard Beckett. I would have read it 18 years ago so some of my details may have been off. Thank you for the help!

As it was confirmed in the comments, it is Genesis by Bernard Beckett.
There is an entrance exam for entering The academy (not a paper written as a school assignment), where protagonist focus on the life of her hero.

Her chosen area of expertise, which she will be questioned over, is on the life of her long-dead hero Adam Forde.

Everything about the hero match.

Adam Forde is the first to act against the extensive security measures. He spots a young girl in a small battered boat that narrowly avoids the explosives placed in the surrounding ocean and, in an act of compassion, rescues and protects her against assassination. He is consequently thrown in prison and is sentenced to participate in an experiment involving artificial intelligence developed by a respected leader of the Republic, Philosopher William.

At the end she is killed.

Pericles enters the examination rooms and breaks Anaximander's neck, disconnecting her for the final time.

